# Import issue for setproctitle on Mac OS,

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

In python, If I try to `import setproctitle` I get the following import error:

```
 ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow_gg-F_Vv1Po_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Py_GetArgcArgv
      Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow_gg-F_Vv1Po_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow_gg-F_Vv1Po_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

What I have tried so far:

- Try to reinstall it (with different flags such as --upgrade and --no-cache)
- Try to use both venv and Pipenv

Info on my system:   System version:    macOS 10.15.2 (19C57), Kernel version:  Darwin 19.2.0

I did not manage to find any information online for this specific import error. Any ideas?

--- Edit

I installed python 3.8 from the official website and, indeed, it works (with that interpreter as base for venv). I previously had python 3.7 installed with brew (brew install python3). I do not know why it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for `Python 3.8` installed directly from Python page.

```
> python3.8 -m pip install virtualenv
> python3.8 -m virtualenv -p \
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 proctest
> source proctest/bin/activate
> python3.8 -m pip install setproctitle
> python3.8
...
...
>>> import setproctitle
>>>
```

Comment: I have python installed from brew, I will try to use python from official website and report back.

Comment: I installed python 3.8 from the official website and, indeed, it works (with that interpreter as base for venv). 

I previously had python 3.7 installed with brew (brew install python3). I do not know why it did not work.

Comment: I had the issue on 3.8.2. Upgrading to Python 3.8.5 and re-installing airflow did it for me.

Comment: reinstall python3.8 from official website works.

Comment: @JohnDavidFive thanks for that! I am on Python 3.8.2 facing the exact same issue. I have the feeling it might be due to this version. However, I am unable to just download `Python 3.8.2` from python.org to validate it's due to the version. I can also imagine it's because of it being the default interpreter from my XCode.