# airflow initdb: undefined symbol: Py_GetArgcArgv

Tags: python, macos, python-wheel

I followed the documentation to install Apache-airflow. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html

When I execute airflow initdb, an error occurs every time.

```
x-MacBook-Pro:~ x$ airflow initdb
 ......
import airflow.utils.dag_processing
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py", line 40, in <module>
    from setproctitle import setproctitle
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Py_GetArgcArgv
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

One answer suggested that this is a problem with the binary package. But I still don't know how to solve that.
This is the link https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/807.

MacOSX 10.15.3

pip 20.0.2

Python 3.7.3

Comment: by any chance did you resolve this?

Comment: @dvakhil no, it's still there.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I had the same issue. macOS 10.15.2.

I had python 3.8 globally installed. I did some research and I found out that the reason was the way that c library `m-darwin.so` was compiled.

This steps help me fixed the issue:

1. Installed pyenv

```
brew install pyenv
```

2. Downgraded to python 3.7.0

```
pyenv install 3.7.0
```

3. Set python 3.7.0 globally

```
pyenv global 3.7.0
```

4. Running `python3 -V` should give you:

```
Python 3.7.0
```

5. Recreated my project environment using virtualenv:

```
python3 -m virtualenv --python=python3.7 my awesome_env
```

6. Activated my env and installed all dependencies and it woorked.

```
source awesome_env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I think this whole process trigger the recompilation of the libraries.

Comment: I think the problem you had was because your `Python3.8.x` version was `x<5`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you doing here but this worked for me and solved my issue.

Comment: @Akhil, I'm not an expert on Python or C libs but I can speculate that the C library was compiled for a different python version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when I was using the system (OS) python3 interpreter, i.e. `/usr/bin/python3`

you can simply install python 3.7 or 3.8 (it works for both) with homebrew:

```
brew install python@3.8
```

Make sure python3 is now pointing to `/usr/local/bin/python3` by running `which python3`.

Then install apache-airflow:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
pip install apache-airflow
airflow initdb
```

Comment: this issue is micro version-specific, I'm still facing the issue on 3.8.9, but it's working on 3.8.5 - https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle/issues/82

Comment: I would recommend using `pyenv` instead of `brew` to manage your python versions. In my experience, `brew` tend to automatically change python version on you (which can totally screw up virtualenvs). `pyenv` lets you actually manage multiple `pythonX.Y.Z` interpreter versions simultaneously.

Comment: `airflow initdb` has been replaced with `airflow db init`

Answer (score 2):

This error is explained more fully in the troubleshooting section here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html

In my case, I had the problem with 3.8.2 installed via homebrew and installing 3.9.4 via pyenv did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in `python 3.7` but Works great for Python 3.8 installed directly from python page, create a new environment and install again apache-airflow in your new environment, be sure you have all dependencies for this version of apache-airflow and you are not using the local environment to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tied to 3.7.x and using pipenv like me, running the latest patch helps.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.10
pyenv global 3.7.10
pipenv --rm
pipenv install --dev --python 3.7.10
```

Answer (score 0):

The setproctitle 1.1.10 module works as expected on macOS Catalina when using python 3.8 installed from the official site.

Python 3.8 download: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Related question: [Import issue for setproctitle on Mac OS,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147788/import-issue-for-setproctitle-on-mac-os)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your help abhiarora

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with python 3. Try creating an `virtualenv` of python 2.7 and install airflow in it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7.3 is causing this issue.
I upgraded to Python 3.7.7 and issue got resolved.

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3.7.7 airflow
workon airflow
pip install apache-airflow
airflow initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following these steps:

*Note: the order of the steps matters!*

- Install the latest version of python, it was 3.8 now it is 3.9.13.
- Create a virtual env.
- Update the pip command by executing `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
- Install apache airflow `pip install apache-airflow`