# Error installing apache-airflow: "Could not build wheels for setproctitle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

Tags: python, pip, airflow, pep517

I'm trying to find some help installing apache-airflow.

I am on MacOS 10.15.7, Python version 3.8.2, and I keep getting an error:

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for setproctitle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I have tried using earlier versions of pip and python to no avail.

Does anyone know what I can do in this situation? I have looked at all the stack overflow questions that popped up with these search terms but none have presented a solution that worked for me so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
>$ pip install apache-airflow
Collecting apache-airflow
  Using cached apache_airflow-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt<2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.7.1)
Collecting flask-caching<2.0.0,>=1.5.0
  Using cached Flask_Caching-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<2.12.0,>=2.10.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601>=0.1.12 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=0.9.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (3.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: colorlog>=4.0.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: unicodecsv>=0.14.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.14.1)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-ftp
  Using cached apache_airflow_providers_ftp-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: dill<0.4,>=0.2.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.3.1.1)
Collecting sqlalchemy<2,>=1.3.18
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.23-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: alembic<2.0,>=1.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4.2)
Collecting sqlalchemy-jsonfield~=1.0
  Using cached SQLAlchemy_JSONField-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources~=1.4
  Using cached importlib_resources-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.20.0
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3,>=2.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.8.1)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-imap
  Using cached apache_airflow_providers_imap-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe<2.0,>=1.1.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Collecting python-slugify<5.0,>=3.0.0
  Using cached python_slugify-4.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-daemon>=2.2.4
  Using cached python_daemon-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting tenacity~=6.2.0
  Using cached tenacity-6.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1
  Using cached Flask_AppBuilder-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting cattrs~=1.1
  Using cached cattrs-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-login<0.5,>=0.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.4.1)
Collecting setproctitle<2,>=1.1.8
  Using cached setproctitle-1.2.2.tar.gz (23 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting python3-openid~=3.2
  Using cached python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting attrs<21.0,>=20.0
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting rich==9.2.0
  Using cached rich-9.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (164 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1,~=1.0
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate<0.9,>=0.7.5 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.8.6)
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn<20.0,>=19.5.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (19.10.0)
Collecting python-nvd3~=0.15.0
  Using cached python_nvd3-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata~=1.7 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lockfile>=0.12.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.12.2)
Collecting psutil<6.0.0,>=4.2.0
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (236 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: croniter<0.4,>=0.3.17 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.3.31)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-http
  Using cached apache_airflow_providers_http-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0,>=2.0.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema~=3.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz>=0.12 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete~=1.10 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.11.1)
Collecting connexion[flask,swagger-ui]<3,>=2.6.0
  Using cached connexion-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4.3)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
  Using cached apache_airflow_providers_sqlite-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting marshmallow-oneofschema>=2.0.1
  Using cached marshmallow_oneofschema-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Collecting pendulum~=2.0
  Using cached pendulum-2.1.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl (124 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas<2.0,>=0.17.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown<4.0,>=2.5.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.6.11)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf<0.15,>=0.14.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property~=1.5 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flask<2.0,>=1.1.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=1.1.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rich==9.2.0->apache-airflow) (0.4.3)
Collecting typing-extensions<4.0.0,>=3.7.4
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting commonmark<0.10.0,>=0.9.0
  Using cached commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Mako in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from alembic<2.0,>=1.2->apache-airflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-editor>=0.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from alembic<2.0,>=1.2->apache-airflow) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from connexion[flask,swagger-ui]<3,>=2.6.0->apache-airflow) (5.3.1)
Collecting openapi-spec-validator>=0.2.4
  Using cached openapi_spec_validator-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting inflection>=0.3.1
  Using cached inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Collecting clickclick>=1.2
  Using cached clickclick-20.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting swagger-ui-bundle>=0.0.2
  Using cached swagger_ui_bundle-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from clickclick>=1.2->connexion[flask,swagger-ui]<3,>=2.6.0->apache-airflow) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.9.3->apache-airflow) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=0.9.3->apache-airflow) (2.20)
Collecting prison<1.0.0,>=0.1.3
  Using cached prison-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-sqlalchemy<0.24.0,>=0.22.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (0.22.3)
Collecting apispec[yaml]<4,>=3.3
  Using cached apispec-3.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<4,>=3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (3.5.1)
Collecting email-validator<2,>=1.0.5
  Using cached email_validator-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-enum<2,>=1.5.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (3.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Babel<2,>=1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy<3,>=2.4 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy-utils<1,>=0.32.21 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (0.36.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from email-validator<2,>=1.0.5->flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (2.9)
Collecting dnspython>=1.15.0
  Using cached dnspython-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask-Babel<2,>=1->flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=2.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask-Babel<2,>=1->flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18->flask-appbuilder~=3.1.1->apache-airflow) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-wtf<0.15,>=0.14.3->apache-airflow) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from importlib-metadata~=1.7->apache-airflow) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jsonschema~=3.0->apache-airflow) (54.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jsonschema~=3.0->apache-airflow) (0.15.7)
Collecting openapi-schema-validator
  Using cached openapi_schema_validator-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas<2.0,>=0.17.1->apache-airflow) (1.18.2)
Collecting pytzdata>=2020.1
  Using cached pytzdata-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-daemon>=2.2.4->apache-airflow) (0.16)
Collecting text-unidecode>=1.3
  Using cached text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python3-openid~=3.2->apache-airflow) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (2019.11.28)
Collecting isodate
  Using cached isodate-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: setproctitle
  Building wheel for setproctitle (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/orange/airflow_testing/airflow-venv/bin/python /Users/orange/airflow_testing/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/gw/f5ssjh4s74x8m0dzzxdj09m40000gn/T/tmp1bbqxe6_
       cwd: /private/var/folders/gw/f5ssjh4s74x8m0dzzxdj09m40000gn/T/pip-install-slsvb38c/setproctitle_46b9decf51e14932ad0abe665916f05b
  Complete output (119 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'setproctitle' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DSPT_VERSION=1.2.2 -D__darwin__=1 -I/Users/orange/airflow_testing/airflow-venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/setproctitle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/setproctitle.o
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
  #error Unsupported architecture
   ^
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
  typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
  typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/setproctitle.c:14:
  In file included from src/spt.h:15:
  In file included from src/spt_python.h:16:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for setproctitle
Failed to build setproctitle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for setproctitle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am on MacOS 10.15.7 Python version 3.8.2

I'm guessing you used the Python 3 bundled/pre-installed with macOS Catalina.

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ /usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.8.2

$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv airflow-venv
$ source ./airflow-venv/bin/activate
(airflow-venv) $ python -V
Python 3.8.2
(airflow-venv) $ pip -V
pip 19.2.3 from /path/to/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(airflow-venv) $ pip install apache-airflow
```

With those commands above, I could reproduce the same error messages about:

```
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
```

The bundled Python 3.8.2 is known to cause those kind of problems when installing certain Python packages that require compilation of some C code. I find that it's better to use Python provided by other sources:

- [From python.org official downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
- [From Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python)
- [From Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python)

Check and pick whichever one you feel you are most comfortable with. I personally use Homebrew:

```
# Install Homebrew (https://brew.sh/)
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

# Install Python3.8
$ brew install python@3.8
$ brew link python@3.8
```

While the latest Python you can install now is 3.9, the [installation guide for apache-airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html#prerequisites) mentions which Python and pip versions are supported:

> Please note that with respect to Python 3 support, Airflow 2.0.0 has been tested with Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8, but does not yet support Python 3.9.
>
> There was a recent (November 2020) change in resolver, so currently only 20.2.4 version is officially supported, although you might have a success with 20.3.3+ version (to be confirmed if all initial issues from `pip` 20.3.0 release have been fixed in 20.3.3). In order to install Airflow you need to either downgrade pip to version 20.2.4 `pip install --upgrade pip==20.2.4`

So follow those recommendations:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.8

$ python3 -m venv airflow-venv
$ source ./airflow-venv/bin/activate
(airflow-venv) $ pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from /path/to/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(airflow-venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip==20.2.4
...
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.2.4
```

Then just install `apache-airflow` same as before:

```
(airflow-venv) $ pip install apache-airflow
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue while installing airflow, I tried to install python using homebrew but get below error:-
 brew install python@3.8
Error: python@3.8: the bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.
  You can install them, if desired, with:
    xcode-select --install
I have python 3.7 and 3.8 installed on my Mac as below, is there any of doing it with them:-
which python3.8
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
Rajnils-MacBook-Air:Airflow rajnilguha$ which python3.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7

Comment: @RajnilGuha Have you tried using the Python commands at the bottom of my answer using your own Python installations? Or have you tried following the error about "Apple Command Line Tools" not being installed, and then installing them? For further debugging questions, please post your own separate question.

Answer (score 0):

For me ,same error occurred
Resolved using home-brew. probably default python was causing the problem.
Also use supported version of pip for airflow.I had to downgrade pip version

Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.1

Successfully installed pip-20.2.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old thread. However, I'm still seeing XCodes default `Python3` to be `Python3.8.2`.

### The error architecture not supported error during installation

First of all. The error

```
  #error architecture not supported
```

Can be fixed by setting `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` before you run pip install. Remember, this should be your architecture you enter here. Probably old MacBooks and the new M1 Macbooks should have a different value here.

### The Python3.8.2 incompatibility with `setproctitle`: `_Py_GetArgcArgv` error

I managed to install it with the tip mentioned above. However, it still appears as mentioned in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147788/import-issue-for-setproctitle-on-mac-os) that `Python 3.8.2` is incompatible with `setproctitle`.
I am getting

```py
Python 3.8.2 (default, Aug 25 2020, 09:23:57) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setproctitle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(~/.venv/airflow_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Py_GetArgcArgv
  Referenced from: ~/.venv/airflow_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ~/.venv/airflow_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

So it appears the best solution is to upgrade your Python3.8 version to anything from 3.8.5 onwards.