# During Instl apache-airflow got the error: subprocess-exited-with-error, Building wheel for setproctitle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: airflow

pip install apache-airflow
pip3.9 install apache-airflow

The Err by Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1

```
Using cached urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for flask-login, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-nvd3, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-slugify, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for termcolor, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for unicodecsv, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blinker, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Flask-JWT-Extended, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: setproctitle
  Building wheel for setproctitle (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for setproctitle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'setproctitle' extension
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for setproctitle
Failed to build setproctitle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for setproctitle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

actually already tried to downgrade the pip version from pip 22.0.3 to 20.2.4
pip install --upgrade pip==20.2.4
like solution in the [thread "Could not build wheels for setproctitle..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430674/error-installing-apache-airflow-could-not-build-wheels-for-setproctitle-which?rq=1)
still the same error

Comment: Are you on a Mac OS? It seems like you don't have XCode installed. If Yes, have you created a venv? If, so, you'll need to source it!

Comment: I had a very similar problem today. I successfully installed Airflow about a month ago, but then I had to rebuild my environment, and when I started again today, I got the same error. I tried to download the binary for "setproctitle" but that didn't work, and then I realized that there are no binaries for 3.10. I downgraded to Pything 3.9 (which I had a month ago), and I was able to reinstall everything as before.